# Wifi Problems for samsung GT-I860

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

Im having problem with connecting wifi with my phone which is Samsung Ace 2 GT-I860. It will connect but in very very low, even if im near the router it still very low connection and it goes and comes back on again. What should i do please? I updated my mobile through kies and still the problem is still there.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have given almost NO information other than you are having trouble with the connection.  To venture a guess, I would check the router since it is the device you are connecting to.